# Retry sidekiq job if it is in dead queue in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, ruby-on-rails-6, sidekiq-cron

I want to write a cron job which fetches the sidekiq job from the dead queue and retry it, as we can do it from sidekiq's Web UI, I want to do the same through the code.

Answer (score 2):

The dead queue is accessed with [Sidekiq::DeadSet](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/mperham/sidekiq/Sidekiq/DeadSet) which has a [`retry_all` method](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/mperham/sidekiq/Sidekiq%2FDeadSet:retry_all).

```
Sidekiq::DeadSet.new.retry_all
```

This is a thin wrapper around iterating over each job in the queue and calling [`retry`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/mperham/sidekiq/Sidekiq/SortedEntry#retry-instance_method). SideKiq::DeadSet is [Enumerable](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html) so you can use methods like `select` and `each`. The [wiki page has a good example](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/API#dead).

```
ds = Sidekiq::DeadSet.new

# Retry only jobs of FixedWorker class whose first argument is 123.
ds.select { |job|
  job.klass == 'FixedWorker' && job.args[0] == 123
}.map(&:retry)
```

Comment: But I don't want to retry all instead I want to check its parameter first and then retry for each job , so individually if want retry then how can I do??

Comment: Please read the API wiki page. https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/API#dead

Comment: @PujaGarg `Sidekiq::DeadSet` is an enumerable. You can use normal enumerable functions like `select` and `each`.